# Having clause for a group count gremlin query

Tags: java, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

I have a query where I need to find the groupCount of a particular type of vertices where the count is greater than 1.

eg

> g.V().hasLabel('airport').limit(40).groupCount()***.as('gc')***.by('region')***.having('gc',gt(1))***

I know this syntax is not valid (especially the bold italic part), it's just to show what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `where()` after you `unfold()` the `Map` to key/value pairs:

```
g.V().hasLabel('airport').limit(40).
  groupCount().by('region').
  unfold().
  where(select(values).is(gt(1)))
```